# Having Problem Finding App ID and App Secret For Facebook Firebase Authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDfpp.jpg)

I want to add Facebook as a new Provider for Firebase Authentication .I cannot find the App Id and App Secret in My Facebook App

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I was asking i can do Facebook Authentication using Firebase for my full stack web project?